# Solving for missing values in a Matrix in Sage

Tags: matrix, sage

I have a 2 by 2 matrix A whose determinant is equal to +- 1
the first row is given as a vector [4,5], but the second is just labeled c and d

I'm confused of how I would find the missing values in the matrix A so together the determinant in +- 1

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!,  Can you show some code; how you create the matrix/ or how it looks like? (in code)

Comment: A = matrix(2,2[a,b,c,d])

Answer (score 0):

Think of Bezout coefficients `c` and `d` so that
`4 d - 5 c` equals the gcd of 4 and 5 (which is one).

These can be found using the "extended gcd algorithm"
(often denoted by "xgcd").